# How to test that Python code is cooperative for concurrency?

Tags: python, async-await, concurrency

If your Python code is not CPU intensive and does some I/O, you can use coroutines to optimize usage of a single CPU core (because of GIL).

> Inside a coroutine function, the `await` expression can be used to suspend coroutine execution until the result is available.

But how do you find non-cooperative parts of your program?

If your code or a third-party lib are making blocking calls, the purpose of using async/await is defeated, your code becomes synchronous.

What are the techniques to test your code for cooperative concurrency issues?

Comment: Blocking calls definitely do not defeat the whole purpose of using async. It's perfectly fine to have small pieces of code that are blocking intertwined with async blocks.

Comment: @matszwecja what's the point of using async frameworks, if you can't fully use its benefits? While a blocking IO call is being made, some other coroutine could do some useful work.

Comment: "While a blocking IO call is being made" - sure, but not every call in the code involves IO.

Comment: @matszwecja the question is about IO. CPU bound cooperative concurrency doesn't make sense in Python because of GIL.